# HTML Tag containing quotes inside JavaScript code with quotes

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing JavaScript code that on click assigns the function getImage the source of the image that is later supposed to be display in the page. However, the quotation marks are giving me a problem.

```
<img src="bill.jpg" class="captify" 
id="teamformat" alt="Bill Gates" onclick="getName('Bill Gates'); 
getMotto('Bill\'s motto'); 
getImage ('<img src=\"http://www.somepage.com/images/team/bill.jpg\"/>');" />
```

How would I fix the quotation marks in the getImage function?
Thank you.

Comment: You only have to escape duplicated quotes in a string, e.g., `fun('this is it\'s final "day"')`

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you don't need to escape double quotes in single quote delimited strings:

```
getImage ('<img src="http://www.somepage.com/images/team/bill.jpg"/>');" />
```

Similarly, `getMotto` can be re-written as:

```
getMotto("Bill's motto");
```

You are getting a problem *because* you are using both style of quotes within a single attribute - you have way too much JavaScript there and you *do* need to escape the inner double quotes (using `&quot;`).

Both of these should be placed within a javascript function that you attach the click event to - don't directly place them in the `onclick` event handler, it is bad practice.

Something like:

```
function getDetailsForBill(){
     getName('Bill Gates'); 
     getMotto('Bill\'s motto'); 
     getImage ('<img src="http://www.somepage.com/images/team/bill.jpg" />');
}
```

Making the `onclick`:

```
onclick="getDetailsForBill();"
```

Though you really should be registering an event listener, using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. That is a great idea, putting everything in a single function. I removed the quotation escape slashes and I get this printed below the clickable image ‘);” />

Comment: @user1655857 - Like I said, avoid all these problems by using a function.

Comment: "_You don't need to escape double quotes in single quote delimited strings_" - Erm, in this context, you do, don't you? HTML doesn't invoke the JavaScript parser when parsing attributes. I'm pretty sure an attribute value cannot contain a raw `"`. That's what `&quot;` is for.

Comment: If using the `onclick` attribute is bad practice, why are you still doing it?

Comment: Thank you again, that has eliminated that problem as you suggested. I put the getDetailsForBill() function below the other functions which it is using in the <script> tag, such as the getName() function, each of which is using this style  document.getElementById('show_name').innerHTML = name. I am trying to display the data provided by the getDetails function by using the <div id="show_name"></div> style but it's not showing the details.

Answer (score 0):

Do not escape it:

```
getImage ('<img src="http://www.somepage.com/images/team/bill.jpg"/>');" />
```